# Is Sidious more powerful than Plagueis?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith, darth-sidious

The Rule of Two dictates that when the Apprentice surpasses the Master in *power*, becoming the greater of the two Lords of the Sith, the Master has served his purpose. The Apprentice must challenge the Master in open combat, fighting to their utmost, as the final trial: killing the Master and taking his place is the final proof that the Apprentice is indeed more *powerful*.

This is how Darth Bane, founder of the Rule of Two, defines power when determining how to ensure each master is more powerful than the last.

Darth Sidious, however, violated the requirements of the Rule of Two: By killing his master, Darth Plagueis, in his sleep, he did not go through the trial of a duel to the death to prove he has indeed become the more powerful of the two.

As such, there is a need to search elsewhere for clues to the answer. Is Darth Sidious more powerful than Darth Plagueis, according to Darth Bane's definition of power being battle superiority?

Canon sources preferred.

Comment: Could you give a source for that definition? Freely available info like wookiepedia doesn't precise how the killing should happen.

Comment: A bit difficult while on the phone. It was demonstrated when Darth Bane had been worried his own apprentice, Darth Zannah, was waiting for him to weaken with old age, which would defeat the purpose of the Rule. The whole point is that the Apprentice must challenge the Master when the latter is still at his peak, and at full power, and prove he can surpass that power. That's why only an open, face-to-face duel will do. Killing your master in his sleep without pitting his power against yours is definitely forbidden

Comment: @thegreatjedi Your comment somehow shows the utter flaw in the rule of two: If there is no apprentice powerful enough to beat his master at the peak, the master will get old and will be beaten then. So the next master isn't necessarily the more powerful one, he either just waited long enough until the master falters or as Sidious did, didn't obey the rule.

Comment: @Thomas That weakness was indeed highlighted. In fact, that example in my prev. comment was exactly used to highlight this one weakness. The Rule of Two had two potentially fatal flaws. That was one. The other is the risk of the Master - or both! - turning to the light before the Apprentice is ready to replace him. In Legends, that happened twice - the Master thought the dark side could be strengthened with the light, but the Apprentice struck him down before he could try. Vader was the second, and as Anakin proceeded to kill Sidious, the last Sith.

Comment: @Thomas As for the risk of the Apprentice killing the Master without properly proving he is indeed the stronger of the two: Well...thankfully(?), by the will of the Force, every Apprentice before Palpatine believed in the principles of the Rule of Two strongly enough to abide by it.

Comment: This is extremely similar to [another question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116988/31936), arguably a dupe. Do you agree that this a dupe?

Comment: Since I think this is a dupe and I haven't heard back from you I've closed this.